# How to combine EventObjects with a SwingWorker progress bar?

Tags: java, swing, events, progress-bar, swingworker

In my project i have a central database class. Everytime the database is accessed i want to display a indeterminate progress bar. So far i managed to establish all the mechanisms to let the database fire events on opening and closing a connection. You can find the details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36811766/5081387).

As far as i've understood is the SwingWorker necessary to let Swing code like the animation of the progress bar run while other code is executed in the background. I also read that you start the long running processes within the `doInBackground()` method, which is in my case not necessary because the long running process of the database access is already started.

I cannot get the SwingWorker part of the solution working correctly. The animation starts when the connection is already closed and with each database access a new Frame is opened:

[image: Several frames opened]

Here is the code:

```
public class UI_DbProgressbar implements Db_ActionListener{

    public void DbActionReceived(final Db_ActionEvent event) {

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

            final JProgressBar jProgressBar = new JProgressBar();
            final JLabel status = new JLabel("Connecting...");
            frame.add(status);
            frame.add("jProgressBar", jProgressBar);

            frame.pack();

        if(event.Status() == Db_Status.CONNECTED)
        {
            System.out.println("DB is connected!"); 

            frame.setVisible(true);

            SwingWorker sw = new SwingWorker() 
            {
                @Override
                protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception 
                {
                    jProgressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
                    System.out.println("In progress!");
                    while(event.Status() != Db_Status.CLOSED);
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public void done()
                {
                    jProgressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
                    status.setText("Successful");
                    jProgressBar.setValue(100); // 100%
                }
            };
            sw.execute(); 

        }
        else if(event.Status() == Db_Status.CLOSED)
        {
            System.out.println("DB connection is closed!");
            frame.dispose();
        }        
        else
        {
            System.out.println("DB idle!" );
        }
    }
}
```

All i need the SwingWorker for is to have the animated progress bar - is it really necessary to use SwingWorker for this task? What's my mistake?

Comment: Swing is the single-thread lib. So when you start your database actions within the Swing-Thread (EDT) your progress will not be refreshed. So you __must__ move your database access code into the `doInBackground` method.

Comment: This will be very painful. Because there are a lot of queries used all over the project and each database action would require to add SwingWorker code (around 50 places in 18 files). Do you know any alternatives?

Comment: sab but true. You need to refactor your application. The only one alternative I know is the [Foxtrot](http://foxtrot.sourceforge.net/docs/introduction.php) lib. But you will also need to refactor your application.